# When popup is displayed, backgroung is not disabled

Tags: html

In my  html code given below ,when i click the login button, login-box pops up and  the background is not   disabled , the background is still working.
I cant find a solution to this, please help....
Please check this code and suggest me what to do...
also given the codepen.io link below...
Thankyou

header:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CO-A-L TESTING</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
<style>
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #212121;
}

nav{

  height: 80px; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #E64A19;
}
.logo h2{
  background-color: #E64A19;
}


.logo a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(226 , 226, 226);
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #E64A19;
}
nav ul li{
  background-color: #E64A19;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #E64A19;
}
.nav-links a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #E64A19;
}

i{
  background-color: #E64A19;
}
/*
.title{
  color: rgb(226 , 226, 226);
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #E64A19;

  text-align:center;
}
.title h2{
 margin-top: 50px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:60px;
 font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
}
*/


.login-box {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  top: 050%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  display: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30,#E64A19);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.login-box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
}

.login-box .user-box {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

.login-box .user-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.login-box .user-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
  background: transparent;
}
.login-page{
   background: none;
}

.login-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
 .login-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: none;
}

 .login-box form a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;

}

.login-box a:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
              0 0 25px #03e9f4,
              0 0 50px #03e9f4,
              0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.login-box a span {
  position: absolute;
   display: block;
}

 .login-box a span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

 .login-box a span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .25s
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .5s
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .75s
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
   0% {
    bottom: -100%;
   }
  50%,100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}
.login-box i{
  position:absolute;
  top: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30,#E64A19);
  cursor: pointer;
}



</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function pop(div) {
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'inline-block';
            }
            function hide(div) {
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
            }
        
        </script>
</head>
```

body:

```
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h2><a href="https://www.vcet.edu.in/"><i class="fas fa-university"></i> VCET</a></h2>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.google.com" title="Support">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="btn" id="button" onClick="pop('login')" title=" Log In">Log In</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
<div class="title">
 <h2></h2>
</div>
<div class="login-box" id="login">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form class="login-page">
    <div class="user-box">
      <input type="text" name="" required="">
      <label>Username</label>
     </div>
    <div class="user-box">
      <input type="password" name="" required="">
      <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
     Submit
    </a>
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle" id="close" onClick="hide('login')"></i>

    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/DhruvKhator/pen/wvMVMxK

Comment: Sounds like you want a lightbox: [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-lightbox-using-html-css-and-javascript/](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-lightbox-using-html-css-and-javascript/)

Comment: no i want the background to be disabled when login box pops up...and  what is the problem with my code

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. More precisely called a "modal": [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal)

Comment: i have already tried it....not working!! @RobMoll